# ler um arquivo txt e listar os candidatos aprovados

Tags: python-3.x

Leia um arquivo 'dados.txt' (em anexo) e liste os candidatos aprovados. O arquivo dados.txt está organizado em seis colunas, separos por ";" , e com o seguinte conteúdo: coluna1>cód. Mat, coluna2>nome completo, colunas 3 a 6> notas nas provas p1 a p4, com decimal(separado por ","

Um candidato é aprovado quando a soma das suas notas (a nota final) é maior ou igual a 25 e nenhuma delas menor do que 2.

A lista de saída deve conter o nome do candidato (aprovado), com 60 posições e sua nota final, com quatro posições (sendo uma decimal)

OBS: Até agora cosegui apenas abrir e ler o arquivo

```
nomeArq = input('nome do arquivo: ')
Lista = opone(nomeArq, 'r')

for linha in Lista: #Lê linha por linha
   linha = linha.rstrip()#rstrip remove os espaços em branco entre linhas
   print(linha)
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Onde está a amostra do arquivo de entrada mencionado ?

Comment: 0816187-9;ZULEIDE MARIA NAZARIO VERAS;1,5;2,25;0,75;8
0123456-0;JESUS DE NAZARE;8,5;9,25;3,75;9,25
9876543-9;CHAPOLIN COLORADO;1,5;5,25;0,75;8,75
2468246-1;MICHAEL JACKSON;4,5;8,5;7,5;5,25
0101010-1;HOMER SIMPSON;1,5;2,25;0,75;6,25

Comment: Algo assim com está acima

Answer (score 0):

Assumindo que seu arquivo de entrada (`dados.txt`) seja algo como:

```
0816187-9;ZULEIDE MARIA NAZARIO VERAS;1,5;2,25;0,75;8
0123456-0;JESUS DE NAZARE;8,5;9,25;3,75;9,25
9876543-9;CHAPOLIN COLORADO;1,5;5,25;0,75;8,75
2468246-1;MICHAEL JACKSON;4,5;8,5;7,5;5,25
0101010-1;HOMER SIMPSON;1,5;2,25;0,75;6,25
```

Segundo as regras, somente `JESUS DE NAZARE` e `MICHAEL JACKSON` seriam aprovados.

Segue um código capaz de determinar os alunos aprovados a partir de um arquivo `.CSV`:

```
import csv

arquivo = "dados.txt"
saida = []

with open( arquivo ) as arqcsv:
    leitor = csv.reader( arqcsv, delimiter=';')
    for linha in leitor:
        notas = [ float(nota.replace(',', '.')) for nota in linha[2:6] ]
        if( all( nota >= 2.0 for nota in notas ) ):
            if( sum(notas) >= 25.0 ):
                saida.append([linha[1], sum(notas)])
print(saida)
```

Saída:

```
[['JESUS DE NAZARE', 30.75], ['MICHAEL JACKSON', 25.75]]
```

Comment: Blz! É isso mesmo, mas o arquivo é em .txt. Desculpe pela falta de conhecimento, é que sou novo nessa área de programação.

Comment: abrindoArq = open(dados.txt, 'r')

Comment: for linha in abrindoArq:

Comment: a saida com o print()

Comment: @WendsonOliveira: ops, corrigido!

Answer (score -1):

Pelo que eu entendi do documento txt, eu aqui abri o arquivo, separei eles por ";" e deixei todos prontos em uma lista. Vê se a minha tentativa te esclarece um pouco sobre como pode ser feita, pois a sua explicação sobre as notas e o txt ficou um pouco confusa, qualquer erro, só adaptar com o que já fiz.

```
nomeArq = input('nome do arquivo: ') 

with open(nomeArq, 'r') as arq:
    Lista = []
    #Lê linha por linha 
    for linha in arq:
        # Notas na coluna 3, 4, 5 e 6. Separei cada coluna aqui.
        linha.split(";")
        # Calcula a media aqui
        somaNotas = float(linha[2]) + float(linha[3]) + float(linha[4]) + float(linha[5])
        if(somaNotas >= 25 and (float(linha[2]) or float(linha[3]) or float(linha[4]) or float(linha[5]) < 2))
            print("Aluno: %s\nNota: %.2f\n", linha[0], float(somaNotas))
```

Comment: Blz! Vou verificar. Muito grato!

Comment: Para ficar mais claro está assim exemplo: 0816187-9;ZULEIDE MARIA NAZARIO VERAS;1,5;2,25;0,75;8;75

Comment: Matricula - Nome - nota1,nota2,nota3,nota4

Comment: Listar alunos aprovados. Um candidato é aprovado com média maior ou iguar a 25 e nenhuma das notas pode ser menor que 2.

Comment: A listagem de saída deve conter o nome do candidato (aprovado), com 60 posições e sua nota final(média), com quatro posições (sendo uma decimal)

Comment: print("Aluno: %s\nNota: %.2f\n", linha[0], float(somaNotas)) # SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: @WendsonOliveira: Seu registro de exemplo possui 7 campos enquanto sua pergunta menciona apenas 6. Qual seria o correto ?

Comment: Esse código não está correto: Há um `SyntaxError` no `if` devido a falta de `:` no final da linha; A formatação da saída na chamada de `print` não vai funcionar como o esperado.

Comment: 6 campos: matricula, aluno, nota1, nota2, nota3, nota4

Comment: Como disse, eu não havia entendido bem o que ele havia explicado... escrevi mais para tentar ajudar ele a encontrar uma forma de se fazer. Se ele conseguiu terminar cumpriu bem o objetivo :)